# How to write a Macro that will loop down a given list?

Tags: vba, excel

I just started learning Excel/VBA and got a simple question. I'm given a list from letter A to Z and need to write a macro in VBA that can find the first letter of a person's first name (e.g. mine is L). The letter needs to come out in a specific cell (i.e. C4) in the same worksheet. And this is what I did but I got 1004 run-time error for "application-defined or object-defined"

```
Sub move()

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    For x = 3 To 28
        If InStr(Cells(x, 1), "D") > 0 Then
            Cells(a, 3) = Cells(x, 1)
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

This is the list:

[image: the list]

What can I do to make this work? Would be appreciated if some pointers are given.

Comment: Where does it look for the names?  And what are the letters used for?

Comment: From the list (column A to Z), I wonder if the picture link works.

Comment: And the letters are basically the list I need to look up to.

Comment: I still don't understand where the names are.  Your code as it exists says it will look through Column A (which is simply letters A-Z) until it finds "D", then copy that cell value into the adjacent cell in Column C, 2 rows up?

Comment: Yes, I just need the first letter of a specific name (e.g. Daniel, "D"). And you're right, the idea of my code is basically what you mentioned, copy the value from the list to the pink cell (C4). But anyway, it's solved now :) Sorry if I didn't explain fully in the first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should correct your code like shown below:

```
Sub CopyName()
Dim a As Integer

a = 1
For x = 3 To 28
    'this will find the names with letter "D"
    If InStr(Cells(x, 1), "D") > 0 Then
        Cells(a, 3) = Cells(x, 1)
    a = a + 1
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

In order to find and copy the first letter of the name in Column A to Column C, use VBA function:

```
Sub CopyFirstLetter()
For x = 3 To 28
    Cells(x, 3) = Left(Cells(x, 1), 1)
Next x
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.